# 2nd chained API not getting called (React + Axios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to chain 2 api calls, first is a POST which creates a new service, 2nd is a call to UPDATE that service with the correct user/admin.

However it's never making it to `api.updateUserRights`

```
export const addService = (service, user, rights) => (dispatch) => {
  const params = {
    name: service,
    disabled: false,
    rights: rights
  };

  console.log('----------------- addService')
  console.log(' service', service)
  console.log(' user', user)
  console.log(' params', params)

  const addUserToService = (user) => api.updateUserRights(key, user);

  api.addService(service, params)
    // First Add the Service
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.ADD_SERVICE,
        payload: {
          service,
          rights
        }
      });
    })
    // Then Update the Admin to have the Service and Rights
    .then(addUserToService(user))
}
```

Thoughts? How could this be re-written?

Comment: You have two codes with `addService` as a name in both of them. I don't get you.

Comment: Sorry bad design, `addService` is the action creator, but `api.addService` is the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` takes a function as a parameter and not a function call.
Try changing the chained `then` to

```
    // Then Update the Admin to have the Service and Rights
.then(res => { addUserToService(user) } )
```